# Spring boot The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem with injection cycle, I tried with annotations @Lazy and @Setter but still doesn't work.
e.g.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class A{
     private final B b;
}
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class B{
     private final A a;
}
```

I added @Lazy annotation to final variables and it doesn't work.
I added @Setter annotation to final variables and it doesn't work.
and I don't know why

Comment: Is this Spring-related?  I'm not seeing any of the stereotype annotations on these classes.  Regardless, this seems like a classic circular dependency issue.  I would rethink the dependencies required by both `A` and `B`, and inject them into both.

Comment: The constructor argument needs to be annotated with `@Lazy` not the field.

Answer (score 1):

We can't have any setters for the final field, because the final variable binding happens once through bootstrap.
@Lazy should declare with constructor argument, for example:

```
   class B{
     B(@Lazy private final A a){
     this.a = a;
   }
     private final A a;
   }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with lombok annotations?

Comment: `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))`. Your IDE might not like it, though ;) You can also use [`lombok.copyableAnnotations`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation, you should add `lombok.config` file to project's root directory containing the following line to achieve copying `@Lazy` annotation from a field to constructor's parameter:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
```

Then, just add `@Lazy` annotation to a field creating circular reference, e.g.:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class A{
     @Lazy
     private final B b;
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class B{
     @Lazy
     private final A a;
}
```